# Removing Nexus 8-speed IGH from hub shell

Tags: shimano, repair, parts, internally-geared-hub, mechanical

**see update at the bottom**

I'm trying to remove my Nexus SG-C6001-8D from its hub shell to grease it. Sadly Shimano's [documentation](https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/dm/DM-CASG001-00-ENG.pdf#45) doesn't cover the process of extracting the internals from the hub shell. The info I can find online is mostly for Alfine hubs, where after removing the sprocket on the drive side, you take off a small plastic cover to reveal a large plastic thread, which can be turned with a special tool to take the cover completely off.

In my case though, this doesn't seem to exist - below the sprocket there's only a large, rubber plastic dust cover that doesn't seem to have a thread anywhere and also cannot be removed by hand.

Are Nexus hubs different in that respect, and the cover does not need to be removed to extract the hub from the hub shell? Or is this because I have a **belt drive** bike, and the process is different than with a traditional chain sprocket?

**Alfine**

after taking off the sprocket
[image]

removing the small ring to access the thread
[image]

the thread
[image]

**My Nexus hub** - note the lack of any thread or teeth to unscrew it, unlike the Alfine

[image]

**update**:

I've disassembled the hub to perform regular maintenance (replacing grease). As it turns out, on this model, the dust cover simply pops onto the drive side of the hub and is not threaded. There's no need to take it off before removing the internal hub - simply undo the bearings and push it out from the non-drive side, the cover will come off together with the rest of the assembly.

Comment: pry the rubber cover off with a tyre lever, see if that lifts it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Edit because I was confused by the original pictures)

Here is how Shimano shows that hub going together:

[image]

The "Right Hand Dust Cap A W/ Seal" lifts off, and then you remove the left side cone and locknut to remove the hub core ("Internal Assembly").

Comment: Well, that's the thing - the Alfine seems to have this toothy seal after you remove the plastic ring around it (see 2nd picture), but the Nexus does not seem to have any of this - just one solid rubber cover with no teeth on it and no obvious way to unscrew it.

Comment: @user4520 edited, sorry

Answer (score 1):

This [German video at 10:00](https://youtu.be/pB_s4lP_xk4) shows how to disassemble the Nexus hub. The Nexus hub indeed doesn't have the additional plastic lockring with the outer teeth. You are apparently supposed to hammer the hub out after unscrewing the bearing conus. Make sure there isn't any dust cover left you can pry off.